# Why horizontal bars from markup are displayed randomly only? CSS bug?

Tags: support, bug

I have noticed several times now, that horizontal bars I give in markup like

> ```
> --------------------------
> ```

just appear randomly at the finally rendered post, even if they appear in preview, or not and vice versa. Take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30742157/1413395) of mine as a sample, where I found that in a reproducible manner for me:

**Preview:**
[image]
**Final render:**
[image]

All of the other horizontal bars in this post render properly as intended.

My currently chosen screen resolution is 1600 x 900.

---

<sub>I'm currently using Chrome Browser, Version 43.0.2357.124 m. If that should matter.</sub>

Comment: For your example, I see the lines in both the previous and the final rendered post, although I am still using Chrome version x..81m

Comment: @psubsee2003 Browser problem then? Display resolution (I have an Acer 17'' laptop)?

Comment: using FF38.0.5, I can see both as well. Have you tried using `<hr />` instead?

Comment: @dippas Could try as a workaround, but shouldn't that markup code end up with the same while it's rendered?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I updated to the current version of Chrome and see no issue.  What OS?  Windows 8 here.  I have a smaller screen... Dell 15", resolution is 1920 x 1080

Comment: @dippas Changed it now, same effect.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can't reproduce it. Using a Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 m

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ humm thats weird. Go with @ psubsee2003 since he is debugging this with you.

Comment: @psubsee2003 _"Windows 8 here"_ Same here. It's really strange, especially the difference between preview rendering and final rendering :-( ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ any add-ins on your side?  Nothing here except Ad-Block but it ignores SE sites

Comment: @psubsee2003 It well might be a screen resolution problem, though weird.

Comment: @psubsee2003 and _@others_ THX a lot for your support anyways!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for bothering, I found it now:

That's not an SO CSS, nor browser or display resolution bug, but just dependent on the chosen magnification level for a particular site.

If I change it to 100%, it displays well for both cases:

[image]

---

<sub>I'm often playing around with magnification, instead of wearing reading glasses as I should :-P ...</sub>

Comment: I almost suggested magnification as a culprit, but I noticed that I was seeing it at 90% and assumed it wasn't the issue

Comment: Maybe you should stop looking at bright monitors and start looking at nice reflections :) http://www.bestbuy.com/site/optoma-3d-ready-dlp-projector-1080p-edtv-43-black/1312439816.p